# Discord Bot won't go online with node . or node main.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, bots

I have been trying to make a Discord bot and I tried to run `node .` in the command prompt, but it won't go online.

Command Prompt:

[image: Command Prompt]

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const client = new Discord.Client();


Client.once('ready', () =>{
    console.log('axtrobot is Online!');
});


Client.Login ('token');
```

Comment: Im new to this site sorry if this post is messy

Comment: You are creating `const client` with a lower case `c` but calling `Client.once` with an uppercase `C`. Try `client.once`. Also not sure about this (I don't know the library) but I think `.once` is supposed to be `.on`. If `client.once` doesn't work, try `client.on`

Comment: @Allister `.once` is correct, it means that the listener only gets run once for the `ready` event no matter how many times it's emitted.

Comment: I see, thank you for the correction.